# After using getpass(), I can no longer type in the linux command prompt. It is recording my keystrokes, but not echoing them

Tags: c, linux, signals, echo, alarm

```
  signal(SIGALRM, handler);
  alarm(5);
  passphrase = getpass("Enter Passphrase:");
  alarm(0);
  exit(0);


void handler(int sig)
{
  if(sig == SIGALRM)
    printf("<Time Out> \n");
  exit(0);
}
```

Here is a fragment of my code. It this times out after 5 seconds, it prints timeout and the next command prompt comes up with the $, but it is no longer echo what I type. However it is recording it and if typed correctly, I can still do an command

Comment: Doesn't really solve your real problem, but probably if you run `reset` you'll get the ability to see what you're typing again.

Comment: Running `stty echo` or `stty sane` is a quick fix. Prolly shouldn't be using `getpass()` though (see warnings in man page). From C, you'd use `tcsetattr(3)` and `ECHO` to control echoing. This is what `stty(1)` (and `getpass()`, though it does other things too) uses under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

No doubt `getpass` (which, by the way, you shouldn't use<sup>1</sup>) is modifying the terminal settings to not echo the password and it would also no doubt turn echo back on if it were allowed to finish.

However, since you're interrupting it before that point, you'll probably have to restore the settings yourself, using something like [`tcsetattr()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetattr).

As an example, see the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

// For saving terminal status.

static struct termios tio;

static void handler (int sig) {
    // Notify user, reset term status and exit.

    printf("<Time Out>\n");
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &tio);

    exit (0);
}

int main (void) {
    char *passphrase;

    // Save terminal setting, probably
    //   need better error handling :-)

    if (tcgetattr(0, &tio) != 0) {
        printf ("urk!\n");
    }

    // Start timer, try to get input.

    signal (SIGALRM, handler);
    alarm (5);
    passphrase = getpass ("Enter Passphrase: ");
    alarm (0);

    // Print it and finish up.

    printf ("You entered '%s'\n", passphrase);

    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It has been marked obsolete in Linux and removed from POSIX some time ago. If you want to know what to use in *preference* to `getpass()`, the answer's in the code above. Use `tcsetattr()` with the `ECHO` option (keeping in mind your signal handler should still restore on exit).